# Finitely generated ring of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can we say that, "by definition", a ring $R[x]$ is finitely generated as an $R$-module for some commutative ring $R$ iff $x^n=q(x)$ for some polynomial $q(x)$ of degree $n-1$ for some $n$?

Comment: For which rings $R \neq 0$ could this happen? If you admit there exists $R$ satisfying this condition, you would have no identity principle for polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite true; $q(x)$ could have degree lower than $n-1$, eg. $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2 - 2)$. I don't think it's quite "by definition"; you should probably prove it eg. if this is homework.

Comment: I repeat: $R[x]$ can never be finitely generated, so the problem has no meaning. Your example $R=\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-2)$ does not work, because $R[t]= \mathbb{Q}[x,t]/ (x^2-2)$ is not finitely generated over $R$.

Comment: @Crostul: I was figuring the OP meant a quotient ring of $R[x]$ rather than $R[x]$ itself and just said it badly.